# Не работает регионы на подпапках wordpress wt geotargeting

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт с чистой темой и установленным на него плагином wt geotargeting
Нужно настроить работу на директориях
Пытался настроить разными способами остановился на этом
Код functions.php:

```
<?php
function custom_rewrite_rule()
{
$region_slug = do_shortcode('[wt_location get=slug/]');
add_rewrite_tag('%location%', '([^/]+)', 'location=');
add_rewrite_rule('^' . $region_slug . '/blog/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php? 
name=$matches[1]&location=' . $region_slug, 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Структура постоянных ссылок:

```
/%location%/blog/%postname%/
```

Код работает на записях блога и главной странице, но не работает на отдельных страницах

Comment: Это есть в платной версии, и то.. ограничено https://web-technology.biz/cms-wordpress/plugin-wt-geotargeting-for-cms-wordpress/nastrojka-sajta-na-osnove-direktorij/

Comment: Я использовал платную версию, но оно не работает на отдельных страницах

Comment: @Tem_Dem Тогда наверное имеет смысл обратиться в поддержку.